# How can I use the LINQ extensions on IList to query the value in nested object?

Tags: c#, .net

Yep, I looked through the offered links before asking :-)

I have a List<foo> where foo is an object with a nested object bar, which has a field called Data.

I cannot figure out the proper syntax for using the IList LINQ extension Contains<> to query the value in foo1.bar.Data.

Intellisense is no help, and MSDN can't understand what I am asking for.

What am I missing here?  I'd like the Contains to essentially say, "In this list of foo, tell me if one or more of the foos contain a nested object bar with the string "hello" in its data field."

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Any`:

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
if (foos.Any(f => f.Bar.data == "hello"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to use .Contains to do this?

Comment: @Joe, no, Contains can't handle this scenario

Comment: Sadness.  I was hoping to take advantage of the many extensions, without having to actually write queries.  While the example above is specific, there's many places where I was hoping to replace loops with those query extensions.

Comment: @Joe, I don't understand what you mean... what extensions are you talking about? Any is an extension method. And you can (often) use Linq extension methods instead of loops.

Comment: Like the contains methods above, where you can just use .Method on your IList container.

Comment: @Joe, you can use `.Any(...)` just as easily.  I'm not following you either.

Comment: Ugh, hit Enter.  At any rate, I wanted to use the .Methods that are listed right off the container object in Intellisense, like the Contains method above, without having to write a separate query.

Comment: Jeez, you are right, I wasn't reading the code.  That does help.  Looks like I'll have to sit down and learn my lambda now :-)

Comment: @Joe, enjoy!  It's like a delicacy you've never tried before.  It tastes funny at first, but eventually you'll find lambdas delicious. ;)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  There was an initial response, which was immediately removed (while I was typing my response), and in that code the poster was actually writing queries against the container. I did not read the second (now first) post, with the improved code.

On the other hand, I'm still a little sad that it's not as simple as .Contains(), which would be possible if my values weren't nested.

Comment: @Joe, here's the thing -- how would the syntax work?  What syntax do you *wish* worked?  I think you'll find that there's no practical way to shoehorn what you want into a `.Contains` metaphor.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it (`Any` definitely seems the right approach to me), but you _could_ use `foos.Select(x => x.Bar.data).Contains("hello")`, but of course that assumes `Bar` isn't null...